# How to use aggregation/ lookup in mongoDB with multi results?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an "Image" collection below ( Note: labels field is an array, because 1 Image maybe have many labels)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("624d182b6a4e7f001ed5cd9f"),
    "is_deleted" : false,
    "labels" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("627a0fbc12458800209dd69c"),
            "labelId" : ObjectId("624d14d76a4e7f001ed5c6ca"),
            "xmin" : 0.440625,
            "xmax" : 0.2953125,
            "ymin" : 0.102083333333333,
            "ymax" : 0.366666666666667
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("627a0fbc12458800209dd69d"),
            "labelId" : ObjectId("624d14d76a4e7f001ed5c6ca"),
            "xmin" : 0.2546875,
            "xmax" : 0.45,
            "ymin" : 0.220833333333333,
            "ymax" : 0.439583333333333
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("627a0fbc12458800209dd69e"),
            "labelId" : ObjectId("624d14d76a4e7f001ed5c6ca"),
            "xmin" : 0.240625,
            "xmax" : 0.48125,
            "ymin" : 0.208333333333333,
            "ymax" : 0.466666666666667
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("627a0fbc12458800209dd69f"),
            "labelId" : ObjectId("624d14d76a4e7f001ed5c6ca"),
            "xmin" : 0.275618374558304,
            "xmax" : 0.436395759717314,
            "ymin" : 0.136470588235294,
            "ymax" : 0.404705882352941
        }
    ],
    "img_name" : "6917328478506479617.jpg",
    "img_originalname" : "frame27406302021-085850.jpg",
    "img_desc" : "Cyber Sercurity multi upload",
    "img_uri" : "http://localhost:8080/resources/images/2022/4/6/6917328478506479617.jpg",
    "img_path" : "/resources/images/2022/4/6/6917328478506479617.jpg",
    "datasetId" : ObjectId("624d14216a4e7f001ed5c459"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-04-06T04:33:47.120Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-10T07:09:48.306Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

And below is "Label" collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("624d14d76a4e7f001ed5c6ca"),
    "is_deleted" : false,
    "labelName" : "Đông",
    "description" : "qw",
    "datasetId" : ObjectId("624d14216a4e7f001ed5c459"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-04-06T04:19:35.985Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-04-06T04:19:35.985Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "datanoiseId" : ObjectId("6261318b23a7a590480f92e6")
}
```

Now I want to lookup to joined all information about the labels into an Image, so I did like that:

```
db.Image.aggregate([
  {
       $match: {
           $and: [{"datasetId": ObjectId("624d14216a4e7f001ed5c459"), "is_deleted": false}]
       }
   },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Label",
      localField: "labels.labelId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "labelDocuments",
    },
  },
  
  { $sort : { "_id" : -1 } }
])
```

And the result I got after I excuted above query below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("624d182b6a4e7f001ed5cd9f"),
    "is_deleted" : false,
    "labels" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("627a0fbc12458800209dd69c"),
            "labelId" : ObjectId("624d14d76a4e7f001ed5c6ca"),
            "xmin" : 0.440625,
            "xmax" : 0.2953125,
            "ymin" : 0.102083333333333,
            "ymax" : 0.366666666666667
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("627a0fbc12458800209dd69d"),
            "labelId" : ObjectId("624d14d76a4e7f001ed5c6ca"),
            "xmin" : 0.2546875,
            "xmax" : 0.45,
            "ymin" : 0.220833333333333,
            "ymax" : 0.439583333333333
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("627a0fbc12458800209dd69e"),
            "labelId" : ObjectId("624d14d76a4e7f001ed5c6ca"),
            "xmin" : 0.240625,
            "xmax" : 0.48125,
            "ymin" : 0.208333333333333,
            "ymax" : 0.466666666666667
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("627a0fbc12458800209dd69f"),
            "labelId" : ObjectId("624d14d76a4e7f001ed5c6ca"),
            "xmin" : 0.275618374558304,
            "xmax" : 0.436395759717314,
            "ymin" : 0.136470588235294,
            "ymax" : 0.404705882352941
        }
    ],
    "img_name" : "6917328478506479617.jpg",
    "img_originalname" : "frame27406302021-085850.jpg",
    "img_desc" : "multi upload",
    "img_uri" : "http://localhost:8080/resources/images/2022/4/6/6917328478506479617.jpg",
    "img_path" : "/resources/images/2022/4/6/6917328478506479617.jpg",
    "datasetId" : ObjectId("624d14216a4e7f001ed5c459"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-04-06T04:33:47.120Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-10T07:09:48.306Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "labelDocuments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("624d14d76a4e7f001ed5c6ca"),
            "is_deleted" : false,
            "labelName" : "Luis",
            "description" : "qw",
            "datasetId" : ObjectId("624d14216a4e7f001ed5c459"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-04-06T04:19:35.985Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-04-06T04:19:35.985Z"),
            "__v" : 0,
            "datanoiseId" : ObjectId("6261318b23a7a590480f92e6")
        }
    ]
}
```

You see, the field "labels" has 4 records, but in "labelDocuments" there is only 1 record? The reason is that when assigning labels to images, I have assigned many labels (with the same labelId) to 1 image, so the lookup command can only join 1 record? So how can I make "labelDocuments in this case have 4 records same "labels" field? Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$lookup` operation can get multiple records. In your data you have only one (`ObjectId("624d14d76a4e7f001ed5c6ca")`), which all your labels are referring to. This is the reason you get only one document in the `labelDocuments` array.

If your goal is to merge the labels, you can add your query a step:

```
{
    $addFields: {
      mergedLabels: {
        $map: {
          input: "$labels",
          as: "i",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$i",
              {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$labelDocuments",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this._id",
                        "$$i.labelId"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
 {
    $unset: ["labelDocuments", "labels"]
  },
```

Like this example: [playground 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oQaEzrS-hQ8)
Which is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047670/mongodb-lookup-and-map-array-of-objects) by @turivishal

If you want to get them in a new array, as you say, you can instead add:

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      labelDocuments: {
        $map: {
          input: "$labels",
          as: "i",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {},
              {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$labelDocuments",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this._id",
                        "$$i.labelId"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

[playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DtFuvE9wikq).

If you want to keep your labels under the image document it is better not to `$unwind` as this will be a costly redundant operation, but as I said, that depends on what you want to do next.

Comment: As I mention above, I known that but i dont know how to fixed it, because one image can assigned many same labels, so I want that the "labelDocuments" field must have same size with "labels"

Comment: The question is why. If you'll explain what you want to do with it, I can find the right way to do it. I guess your query continues afterwards...

Comment: Is there a case where the labels on the image document are referring to more than one label?

Comment: There are several ways to go, the right one depends on your query's next steps

Comment: Thanks you so much, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

you should unwind first.

```js
db.Image.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      $and: [{
        "datasetId": ObjectId("624d14216a4e7f001ed5c459"),
        "is_deleted": false
      }]
    }
  },

  {
    $unwind: "$lables"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Label",
      localField: "labels.labelId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "labelDocuments",
    },
  },

  {
    $sort: {
      "_id": -1
    }
  }
])
```